# PendSV and SVCall in RTOS

Tags: arm, embedded, cpu, freertos, rtos

Both PendSV and SVCall are called from the software - SVCall by calling svc instruction, PendSV by setting particural register of Cortex-M. PendSV is intended for context switching and SVCall is intended  to access OS kernel functions and device drivers.

1. What determines that PendSV is used for context switching? Why doesn't SVCall do it? As far as I know it is possible to configure the priority of SVCall to the low value.
2. What are the device drivers, that we cannot acces beyond the SVCall, in the Thread mode in spite of handler? Does it also apply to FreeRTOS? I've never used SVC in order to interact with hardware.
3. PendSV stands for Pendable Service and SVCall stands for Supervisor Call, why they are name like that? What is the origin?

I would like to know something more than "PendSV is used for context switching and SVCall is used for enabling the scheduler". I couldn't find more informations.

Cheers

Comment: These are very good questions please update the thread if you get any answer from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

PendSV is used to pend an service call. It can be pended from interrupt and will occur on the exit from the interrupt. If you do an SVC call from an interrupt you will get a hard fault.

SVC calls are immediate, PendSV leaves it pending until it can execute.

SVC calls are only required to interact with the HW when using unprivileged code. For example when using the MPU, the user code should generally be unprivileged. In order to access anything privileged then it needs to be done via an SVC call.

Comment: Calling SVC from an interrupt does not cause fault.

Comment: SVC causes a fault when it cannot run immediately. This happens when the SVC priority is insufficient for the context in which it is called. If called from an ISR, the SVC priority must be higher (lower number) than the priority of the ISR.

Answer (score 1):

I think the designed usages are different.

ARM Cortex-M has two modes, thread mode and handler mode. Using the Memory Protection Module (MPU) memory addresses will normally be placed off limits in thread mode. A thread of operating code therefore needs a way to enter interrupt mode. This is done using the SVC instruction which in turn places the processor in handler mode with the MPU turned off.

Cortex-M has prioritized interrupts to allow true realtime behaviour. This allows interrupt handler to run immediately on an interrupt and run time critical code. Most of the time a lot of processing can take place (and therefore should take place) later. This is what the PendSV interrupt is for. It is can operate at lower priority and run once any other pending interrupts have been attended to. On this this is called the "bottom half" of the interrupt controller. Scheduling is one of these lower priority tasks. Scheduling a PendSV is not something a non-privileged thread will be allowed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The justification for having two separate exceptions for accomplishing basically the same thing (service a supervisor call/syscall) is provided in the [ARMv7-M reference manual](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f8fef3af86e16515cdbf816) straight from the dragon's mouth.  Here is the relevant excerpt:

> **Use of SVCall and PendSV to avoid critical code regions**
>
> Context switching typically requires the processor to execute a critical region of code with interrupts disabled, to
> avoid context corruption of key data structures during the switch. This can be a severe constraint on system design
> and deterministic performance. ARMv7-M can support context switching with no critical region, meaning the
> processor does not have to disable interrupts.
> An ARMv7-M usage model to avoid critical regions is:
>
> - Configure both SVCall and PendSV with the same, lowest exception priority.
> - Use SVCall for supervisor calls from threads.
> - Use PendSV to handle context-critical work offloaded from the exception handlers, including work that
>   might otherwise be handled by the SVCall handler.
>
> Because SVCall and PendSV have the same execution priority they cannot preempt each other, therefore one must
> process to completion before the other starts. SVCall and PendSV exceptions are always enabled, meaning each
> executes at some point, once the processor has handled all other exceptions. In addition, the associated exception
> handlers do not have to check whether they are returning to a process on exit with this usage model, as the PendSV
> exception will occur when returning to a process.
>
> This usage model always sets PendSV to pending to issue a context switch request. However, a system can use both
> SVCall and PendSV exceptions for context switching because they do not interfere with each other.
>
> **Note**
> This is not the only usage model for avoiding use of critical code regions. Support for avoiding critical code regions
> is a key feature of ARMv7-M, specifically included in the specification of the SVCall and PendSV exceptions.

TLDR: the idea seems to be to offload the small critical region of code involved in context-switching to the PendSV handler, avoiding the need to mask interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

PendSV is an interrupt-driven request for systerm-lever service. In an OS environment, use PendSV for context switching when no other exception is active. The context switching must happen during the return from an interrupt, such as Systick.
But PendSV is not that special for context switching, in principle you could use any other asynchronous exception or interrupt for the purpose of context switching.